# Observable Map does not cast to typescript class

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using angular 2 and I am trying to call an endpoint to return a collection of objects.

I have the following TypesScript class

```
export class Route
{
    public branchId: number;
    public branch: string;
    public isTest: boolean = true;
}
```

I have a api endpoint which returns the following Json

```
[{"id":610,"branch":"Coventry"},{"id":620,"branch":"Shoreham"}]
```

I have a route service which calls the endpoint using the following code

```
public getRoutes(): Observable<Route[]>
{
    const url = 'http://localhost/routes';

    return this.http.get(url)
        .map((response: Response) =>
        {
            const routes: Route[] = response.json() as Route[];
            if (routes.length > 0) {
                console.log(routes[0].isTest);
                //This returns undefined I was expecting the boolean value true
            }
            return routes;

        }
        )
        .catch(e => this.httpErrorService.handleError(e));
}
```

It appears that the response.json() is not being cast to data type Route. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do a strict cast like that in TypeScript and have the objects become that type. The cast is simply a transpiler trick to tell the rest of your code that you are working with a `Route` array. To truly get the json data to be of type `Route` and not just `Object` you can use the `assign` method to type them like so:

```js
const routes: Route[] = (response.json() as []).map((obj) => {
     return Object.assign(new Route(), obj);
}) as Route[];
```

If the json data does have all of the properties set then there is no need to use the `assign` method because at that point you are developing against an interface which should work as if you were working with the typed object.