# TypeError: getPosition is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

From my xx.model.ts:

```
export class ReferenceObject {
  name: string;
  position: Position;
  public getPosition() : Member {
    return this.position;
  }
}

export class Position {
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
}
```

And from my map.component.ts:

```
allObjects : ReferenceObject[] = [];

// allObjects is subscribed to an observable from xx.service.ts

private renderReferenceObjects() {
  var i = 0;
  this.allObjects.forEach ( nextObject => {
    this.objects[i] = this.viewer.entities.add ({
      name : nextObject.name,
      position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(nextObject.getPosition().longitude, nextObject.getPosition().latitude),
      billboard : {
        scale : 1.0,
        image : 'assets/img.png'
      }
    });
  }
});
```

What is the problem?  Why can't I access this method?  It is set to public, and I can reference, for example, nextObject.name, as seen above, with no issues.  It is not until I get to the line where I try to access that member function that an error appears.

**Note:** I've reviewed the code and it looks right, but there might be typos; I had to make a lot of modifications when transcribing this code.  If there's some major typo that would prevent the code from transpiling or running at all, that is definitely not the cause of my problem, but please do point it out in the comments and I'll correct it.

**Edit:** Replacing all instances of nextObject.getPosition() with nextObject.position worked perfectly.  I'm still very curious about why that works but the method does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the code running by directy referencing the member variable instead of using a getter.  Specifically, I replaced all instances of nextObject.getPosition() with nextObject.position, but I'm still curious why calling the method didn't work.

Comment: allObjects needs to be referenced to an array of ReferenceObject class so that each nextObject is a ReferenceObject.

Comment: @DanielH.J. It is.

Answer (score 2):

You are looping `allObjects`:

```
this.allObjects.forEach ( nextObject => {
```

## Answer

Only logical reason is that there is at least one object in `allObjects` *that is not an instance of `ReferenceObject`*. Hence the error.

Comment: There isn't though.  allObjects defined as an array of ReferenceObject, and it is mapped in the service layer directly from the REST API.

Comment: @ClintonJ basarat is correct here, you have not explicitly set your objects as an **instances** of your class `ReferenceObject`, therefore you don't have access to class methods. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737654/observable-map-does-not-cast-to-typescript-class

Comment: So even though allObjects was defined as an array of ReferenceObjects, and every member is a ReferenceObject, nextObject is not considered explicitly a ReferenceObject?  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @ClintonJ Well, have you assigned your response with only `allObjects : ReferenceObject[] = [];`? Like in the link I provided, that does not make them as **instances** of `ReferenceIbject`, you need to explicitly use for example `map` and map all properties separate, or like in the link I provided using `Object.assign`. Or make your constructor as such that you can just map them like `myResponse.map(x => new ReferenceObject(myResponse))`